# return view from different controller.wrong url. asp mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-controller, asp.net-mvc-views

I am currently in the **shared controller** after a **post** from the client. 
now, i want to return a view from the **Technician controller**
i tried:

```
return View("../Technician/OrderDetails", model);
```

and its working... but the url stays the same and does not change to the right one (it stays the same like i have never moved a page).
i tried to use:

```
return RedirectToAction("OrderDetails", "Technician", new { Id = model.Id });
```

and this is actually goes to the correct view but when i return to the client i get "jquery is undefined" error in the client.

is there any solution?

Comment: Are you using Ajax call to post data?

Comment: Is the first page using a layout file in the view?